# Transformation Law of Connection Coefficients

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I am currently studying GR by myself and don't quite understand the derivation of the transformation law of the Christoffel symbols.

Previously we derived that:
$$\nabla_a Y^b=e_a(Y^b)+\Gamma^b_{ca}Y^c$$

In our notes the symbols are defined as follows:
$$\Gamma^i_{jk} := dx^i\left(\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)$$
Then the partial derivative operator is transformed using the chain rule.
$$\Gamma^i_{jk} := dx^i\left(\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k}\frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}\right)$$
Then the covariant derivative is applied. This is the step I don't quite understand. We get:
$$\Gamma^i_{jk} := dx^i\left(\frac{\partial^2 y^l}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}+\frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^j}\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}\right)$$

I guess we used the Leibniz rule here.
But shouldn't we get this:

$$\Gamma^i_{jk} := dx^i\left(\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k}(\frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^j})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}+\frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^j}\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l})\right)$$

I understand all the subsequent manipulations on the second term, but why does the covariant derivative reduce to a partial derivative in the first term?

Comment: On functions the covariant derivative is just the vector aplied to the function. $\nabla_X f = X(f)$ or $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f)$.

Comment: ok I think I got it now thanks.